# Why can a string literal be implicitly converted to char* only in certain case?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, string-literals

```
void f(char* p)
{}

int main()
{
    f("Hello"); // OK

    auto p = "Hello";

    f(p); // error C2664: 'void f(char *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 
          // from 'const char *' to 'char *'
}
```

The code was compiled with VC++ Nov 2012 CTP.

> §2.14.15 String Literals, Section 7
>
> A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is
>   the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage
>   duration.

Why is `f("Hello")` OK?

Comment: A more descriptive question would be "Why does my compiler not report an error with `f("Hello")`?"

Comment: @DrewDormann -but your title only helps tenOP - for other users the more generic title is of use - +1 for the title

Comment: @Mark I think the title is fine.  The question about "OK" is misleading.

Comment: In C, p is an `int`, not a `const char*`. It's been declared with auto scope, but no type (so defaults to `int`). The C tag on this question should be removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This behaviour differs between C and C++, at least in theory.

**In C:** a string literal decays to a non-const pointer.  However, that doesn't make it a good idea; attempting to modify the string through that pointer leads to undefined behaviour.

**In C++:** it's never ok (AFAIK).<sup>*</sup>  However, some compilers may still let you get away with it.  GCC, for example, has the [`-Wwrite-strings`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) flag, which is enabled by default (at least in 4.5.1 onwards).

---

<sub>* In C++11, at least.  (I don't have older specs to hand.)</sub>

Comment: I compiled it as C++ code, but it's OK.

Comment: I agree, in C it's allowed because const wasn't part of the language a long time back, and thus it is allowed to make sure code using literals to pass into functions that are non-const still works.

Comment: just a detail: in C++03 the conversion from literal to char* was supported, but as I recall deprecated; anyway in C++11 it's removed, not valid code

Comment: Given that the code contains the C++11 `auto` feature, I can't imagine it was compiled with an "older compiler". This answer also doesn't explain why a compiler (old or not) would let you get away with the first usage, but not the second.

Comment: @sepp2k: Microsoft's compilers have never been good at standards-compliance.

Comment: Enable `String Pooling` and you won't be able to write to strings and you'll likely get a warning for the implicit conversion to char* too.

Answer (score 7):

```
f("Hello");
```

Even this is not okay in C++. The compiler should give diagnostic, or else it needs to be updated.

In C++, `"Hello"` is convertible to `const char*`, not `char*`.

The conversion from `"Hello"` to `char*` is allowed in C++03, though it is **deprecated**. And in C++11, the conversion is invalid, and the code is ill-formed.

Comment: it is still supported for backwards compatibility I believe, but deprecated

Comment: I compiled it in latest VC++ Nov 2012 CTP

Comment: Well, good luck with updating the compiler. Microsoft is known for sucking at adhering to standards (which is why they don't have a C99 compiler either).

Comment: @AndyProwl: I think it was deprecated in C++03, and ill-formed in C++11.

Answer (score 7):

The difference between

```
f("Hello");
```

and

```
f(p);
```

is that the former involves a literal. In C++03 conversion from string literal to `char*` (note: not `const`) was supported. It isn't supported any longer in C++11, but few if any compilers have yet caught up with that rule change.

Comment: +1 This best answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think because auto keyword. it's type deduction so compiler doesn't know it how to convert to char* anymore.

Comment: That's not the problem. A string literal is `const char*`, not `char*`. `f("Hello")` should be punished with a type error, and it isn't.